# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already

Tags: java, sql, sqlexception

I have this exception in my code, so :

Here is the code where I have the exception :

```
private void assignCoursesToStudents() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

    ConnectionToDatabase connectionToDatabase = new ConnectionToDatabase();

Random random = new Random();

List<Student> students = generateStudents();
    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
    int randomNumberOfStudentsToOneCourse = random.nextInt(3) + 1;

    Set<Integer> randomInts = new HashSet();
    while (randomInts.size() < randomNumberOfStudentsToOneCourse) {
        randomInts.add(random.nextInt(10) + 1);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < randomInts.size(); j++) {
        insertStudentsToCoursesToDatabase(i, j, randomInts,connectionToDatabase);
    }
}
```

}

insertStudentsToCoursesToDatabase method :

```
 private void insertStudentsToCoursesToDatabase(int i, int j, Set<Integer> randomInts, ConnectionToDatabase connectionToDatabase) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {



    try {
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connectionToDatabase.connectToDatabase()
                .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO students_courses (student_id, course_id) VALUES(?, ?)")) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, i + 1);
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, (int) randomInts.toArray()[j]);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
// HERE I HAVE AN EXCEPTION!

    }
}
```

Also I have the class where I connect to Database :

```
public class ConnectionToDatabase {

public Connection connectToDatabase() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\db.properties"));
    Properties properties=new Properties ();
    properties.load (bufferedReader);
    String driverName= (String) properties.get ("jdbc.sql.driver");

    String url= (String) properties.get ("jdbc.sql.url");
    String username = (String) properties.get ("jdbc.sql.username");
    String password= (String) properties.get ("jdbc.sql.password");
    Class.forName(driverName);

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            url, username, password);


    return connection;
}
```

}

And my exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
at com.foxminded.sql.util.GeneratedData.insertStudentsToCoursesToDatabase(GeneratedData.java:58)
at com.foxminded.sql.util.GeneratedData.assignCoursesToStudents(GeneratedData.java:41)
at com.foxminded.sql.util.GeneratedData.generateTestData(GeneratedData.java:23)
at com.foxminded.sql.dao.SchoolDaoImplementation.initializeTheDatabase(SchoolDaoImplementation.java:360)
at com.foxminded.sql.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

When I am trying to run code without class "ConnectionToDatabase" and make connection directly in the class I need, I didn't have any errors.

Comment: Have you checked psotgres and queried how many active connections/clients it thinks there are? does this number exceed the number allowed by your current postgres configuration?

Comment: @Gavin How can I increase possible connections?

Comment: @Gavin I don't know how to check it

Comment: Ah, me either, I was suggesting a cause of investigation.  You would need to be able to access postgres (assuming there is a connection available) using pgadmin.  I would google for something like "postigres  query available connections" or "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already"
Its what I usually do when faced with an exception I dont know how to solve

Comment: @Gavin I did it but I didn't find any property solution for my problem